# I am trying to make the "more" button display additional info without loading the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to make the "more" button display additional info without loading the whole page. I have looked up online and I know I could use AJAX for that, but I just started learning JavaScript so I have no idea how to do AJAX coding. I am not sure if there's an easier way to update the content on web-page without loading the website. Index.html is the main file (home page) and main_test.js is the javascript file which changes the content on page.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<!--
    Theory by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license 
    (templated.co/license)
    -->
<html>

<head>
    <title>ResuMaker</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main_test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">ResuMaker</a>
            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="build.html">BUILD A RESUME</a>
                <a href="login.html">SIGN IN/CREATE AN ACCOUNT</a>
                <a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a>
                <a href="contacts.html">TALK TO US</a>
            </nav>
            <a href="#navPanel" class="navPanelToggle"><span class="fa fa-bars">
                </span></a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <section id="banner">
        <h1>Welcome to Resumaker</h1>
        <p> A free resume builder that helps you create professional resumes.</p>
    </section>

    <!-- One -->
    <section id="one" class="wrapper">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; font-weight : 500">How the<strong>ResuMaker </strong> works</h1>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="flex flex-3">
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2 style="text-align: center"> <strong> 1 </strong><br /></h2>
                    </header>
                    <p id="demo1" style="text-align: center"> You will input basic
                        information in the form input fields.</p>
                    <footer>
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                            <a href="#" onclick="howitworks_1()" class="button special">More</a>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2 style="text-align: center"><strong> 2 </strong><br /></h2>
                    </header>
                    <p id="demo2" style="text-align: center">We will process your inputted
                        information from our website. </p>
                    <footer>
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                            <a href="#" onclick="howitworks_2()" class="button special">More</a>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2 style="text-align: center"><strong> 3 </strong><br /></h2>
                    </header>
                    <p style="text-align: center" id="demo3">Then we let you select a
                        predefined resume template all with different fonts and designs</p>
                    <footer>
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                            <a href="#" onclick="howitworks_3()" class="button special">More</a>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.js:

```
function saveFormAsTextFile()

{    

  var textToSave = 'First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone Number, Location, 
  LinkedIn, School Name\n'+

  document.getElementById('first_name').value+","+
  document.getElementById('last_name').value+","+
  document.getElementById('user_email').value+","+
  document.getElementById('phone_number').value+","+
  document.getElementById('location').value+","+
  document.getElementById('linkedin').value+ ","+
  document.getElementById('school_name').value;


//---For CSV
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
downloadLink.target = '_blank';
downloadLink.download = 'resume.csv';
downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();

}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function howitworks_1() {

 document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
"You will input basic information in the form input fields. We create your 
resume when you input information such as personal information, educational 
history, work experience and skills.";

}

function howitworks_2() {

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
"We will process the inputted information. The inputted information will be 
collected, stored, converted and in turn generate arrays of information 
which can be transformed into a resume.";

}

function howitworks_3() {

document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =
"Then we let you select a predefined resume template all with different 
fonts and designs. Then, we will generate a resume based on your defined 
template and all you to save it as a PDF, or Microsoft Word document.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AJAX you could just use CSS transitions to create what I believe is the desired effect. As long as you're using max-height instead of height in CSS the property can be animated. So you get a smooth transition instead of an appear disappear visual.
As long as the content isn't changing AJAX isn't necessary. I made it so the button both opens and closes as well. If you just want it to open and stay open just switch toggle to add.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p')
let button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  p.classList.toggle('open')
})
```

```css
p {
  max-height: 16px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.open {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height ease-in-out 500ms;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend mauris eu sollicitudin semper. Donec vestibulum ac eros id egestas. Praesent sit amet elementum nibh. Etiam quam libero, ullamcorper nec fringilla sit amet, pretium nec nunc. Sed convallis justo tellus, vel porttitor leo egestas a. Sed ac vestibulum libero, vel.
</p>
<button>More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`<span id="someID"></span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="moreButton1" onclick="howitworks(1)">More</button>
<span id="someID2"></span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="moreButton2" onclick="howitworks(2)">More2</button>`

Then to update the messages:

```
function howitworks(num){
switch(num){
  case 1:
      $("#someID").text("Message for howitworks_1");
      $("#someID").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
      break;
  case 2:
      $("#someID2").text("Message for howitworks_2");
      $("#someID2").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
      break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried that and it stopped loading the whole page; however, it would not update the content when I press the button.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, by 'content', what you meant is the message changes when the the different 'More' button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: It's not working for me. I am trying to make it work for my code, but it does not seem to work. I am trying not to change my code a lot since I am using different tags for some of the things you mentioned in your code.

Comment: What I would suggest is to copy and paste my code in a fresh new page and try whether it works as you intended, and then using that concept and idea to modify yours.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easier way than AJAX. But this doesn't have to be hard at all. Take a look at jquery's ajax, and look at the examples there:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/